# add a button watch later or attend

Tags: django

Now I have a user table, courses table,
I created 2 tables, attend, watch later
which have a one to many with user and many to many with courses
I want when the user press attend, the course will be added to attend table with user = user ,

## models.py

```
class Course_Attendance_sheet(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, blank=None, null=True)
  course = models.ManyToManyField(Course_dir, default=None, blank=None, null=True)
class Course_dir(models.Model):
  id_CO = models.ForeignKey(Specialization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

## views.py

```
def attend(request,*args, **kwargs):
  request.session.set_expiry(0)
  course_id = request.GET.get("course")
  if course_id:
    course_instance = get_object_or_404(Course_dir, id=course_id)
  attend_id, attend = Course_Attendance_sheet.objects.get_or_create(person =request.user, course= course_instance)
  attend_id.save()
```

UnboundLocalError at /attend-done/
local variable 'course_instance' referenced before assignment
I'm sure tables are right, I added data through admin panel, How can I do it with html

```
<form id='add-form' method='GET' action="{% url 'courses.views.attend' %}">
                                        <input id='submit-btn' type='submit' value='Attend' class='btn btn-default' />
                                    </form>
```

Comment: May you post your models.py?

Comment: done but it is correct, I already added a data within admin panel, the problem in the template with the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement might return `False` and in this case `Course_instance` is not defined. You should add exception or an `else` branch. I would do it this way:

```python
def attend(request,*args, **kwargs):
  request.session.set_expiry(0)
  course_id = request.GET.get("course")
  if course_id:
    course_instance = get_object_or_404(Course_dir, id=course_id)
    attend_id, attend = Course_Attendance_sheet.objects.get_or_create(person =request.user, course= course_instance)
    attend_id.save()
  else:
    print('What happened to this course?')
```

Note that the indentation changed.